# Sony ToFAR: How to change the default front ToF camera resolution to 640x480

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sony

- OS: macOS 12.4
- Unity Version: 2020.3.36f1
- ToFAR V1.1.0
- iPad pro 11 gen2

I am developing with ToFAR, recently released by sony.
https://developer.sony.com/us/develop/tof-ar/download

I would like to change the default setting for the resolution of the ToF front camera at startup. I have tried several things and have yet to solve the problem.

The default front camera resolution is 640x360, but I want to change it to 640x480.

What I have tried

- "use front camera asdefault" = True
- Edited, TofAr/V0/Resources/DeviceProfiles/ipad_pro11_gen2_v1.0.0.json

> "defaultDepthResolutionWidth": "640",
> "defaultDepthResolutionHeight": "480" // default is 360

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHNHd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfUh9.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your inquiry about ToF AR.

The current version of ToF AR does not support the default configuration change of the front camera.

Set ToFARTofManager.autoStart to false, specify the desired Configuration with  ToFARTofManager.StartStream(CameraConfigurationProperty,Voolean)from the script, and start Stream.

For details, please refer to the ToF AR reference.

https://developer.sony.com/develop/tof-ar/development-guides/reference-api-en/reference/api/TofAr.V0.Tof.TofArTofManager.html#TofAr_V0_Tof_TofArTofManager_autoStart

https://developer.sony.com/develop/tof-ar/development-guides/reference-api-en/reference/api/TofAr.V0.Tof.TofArTofManager.html#TofAr_V0_Tof_TofArTofManager_StartStream_TofAr_V0_Tof_CameraConfigurationProperty_System_Boolean_

Yours truly,

ToF AR support Team